# Stop auto generate code from class diagram

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

I'm using the class diagram for visual studio professional 2013 and whenever i change something either in code or in the class diagram they update one another. This is not the behaviour I want, i want to be able to generate the code when I **want to** and I don't want changes in code to affect the UML.

Is there a way to stop this 'synchronization' between the diagram and the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That synchronization is the whole idea of the class diagram.